# How to add custom converters for mongodb with spring-boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

## Background

I have a spring-boot project (written in kotlin) using a MongoDB. I have the following entity class:

```
@Document("my_entity")
data class EntityClass(
    @Id
    val id: ObjectId = ObjectId(),
    // some vals holding the payload
    val accessRestriction: AccessRestrictedEntity
): AccessRestrictedEntity by accessRestriction
```

AccessRestrictedEntity is meant to implement the cross cutting concern of access controll across different entities/different payloads using the [delegation pattern](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html). It looks like this:

```
interface AccessRestrictedEntity {
    val owner: UserId
    val authorisedViewers: List<UserId>

    // some methods
}

data class AccessRestrictedEntityImpl(
    override val owner: UserId, 
    override val authorisedViewers: List<UserId> = emptyList()
) : AccessRestrictedEntity {
    // method implementations
}
```

UserId is just a wrapper for a UUID (originating in an external service) used for additional type safety so I don't confuse them with other UUIDs. (I tried experimental inline value classes but those don't seem to play nice with MongoDB.)

```
data class UserId(val value: UUID)
```

## The need for custom converters

Now this works so far but gets stored in MongoDB as objects with UUIDs turning into binary data.
I want to flatten it out to

1. Get rid of the wrapper class (since its only purpose is to ensure type safety in code)
2. Display the UUID as a plain string (to ease debugging and manual cross-referencing of the external service the UserIds originate in)

## Adding custom converters

To realise the desired flattening I added custom converters:

```
@WritingConverter
class AccessRestrictedEntityWriteConverter : Converter<AccessRestrictedEntity, DBObject> {
    override fun convert(source: AccessRestrictedEntity): DBObject {
        val dbObject: DBObject = BasicDBObject()
        dbObject.put("owner", source.owner.value.toString())
        dbObject.put("authorisedViewers", BasicDBList().apply {
            addAll(source.authorisedViewers.map { it.value.toString() })
        })
        return dbObject
    }
}

@ReadingConverter
class AccessRestrictedEntityReadConverter : Converter<DBObject, AccessRestrictedEntity> {
    override fun convert(source: DBObject): AccessRestrictedEntity {
        val accessRestriction =
            AccessRestrictedEntityImpl(owner = UserId(UUID.fromString(source.get("owner") as String)),
                authorisedViewers = (source.get("authorisedViewers") as BasicDBList).map {
                    UserId(UUID.fromString(it as String))
                })
        return accessRestriction
    }
}
```

And registered them in a config class (The rest of the configuration is done automatically by spring from an application.yml file. I don't have a MongoDB config class.)

```
@Configuration
class ConverterConfig {
    @Bean
    fun mongoCustomConversions(): MongoCustomConversions = MongoCustomConversions(
        listOf(
            AccessRestrictedEntityWriteConverter(), AccessRestrictedEntityReadConverter()
        )
    )
}
```

This works fine for writing data. The saved entity looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64da2ff7d738057c6bab15dd"
  },
  // my payload
  "accessRestriction": {
    "owner": "2d67c173-fad1-44ed-9abc-9d5c7a85bcf7",
    "authorisedViewers": [
      "0ca00fe9-590a-4949-a022-defec0e5f659"
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to read it from the DB. It fails with the exception `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [one.material.fscmmvp.domain.release.AccessRestrictedEntity]: Specified class is an interface`.

## Question

How do I get this to work? I have to keep AccessRestrictedEntity an interface because it has to be one for the delegation pattern to work. How does spring get involved here in the first place with its bean instantiation? Is this whole thing I'm attempting the wrong approach and I have to fundamentaly restructure my code?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your class with @BsonDiscriminator
This should allow the driver to instantiate the correct class.

Comment: Which class?
The converted class `AccessRestrictedEntityImpl`? Or the entity class `EntityClass`? Or the converters `AccessRestrictedEntityWriteConverter` and `AccessRestrictedEntityReadConverter`?